# UIPopoverController in UINavigationController

Tags: ios, xamarin, uinavigationcontroller, uipopovercontroller

I have a storyboard setup with the following hierarchy:

```
NavigationController > ViewController1 > Popover > ViewController2
```

However, when I move from the popover to ViewController2, I lose the back navigation and it is presented as a modal view.  What I want is to be able to go back from ViewController2 to ViewController1.  I have tried embedding the Popover in a NavigationController but then everything after appears in the popover.  Can anyone help?

Comment: Try to use "show" or push in code.

Comment: `UIPopoverController` is only available for modal presentation, if you want go back to VC1, just simply make a button and call `self.dismissViewController..`

Comment: I did look at this, only trouble is, I then lose my Tab Navigation at the bottom with this approach.

Comment: It should be ok if you pass a VC1 reference to your PopOver. Then if you want to move to VC2 you need to do this on the VC1 reference and call dismiss onto the PopOver.

Comment: Thank you @tequilaslammer this works, I now dismiss the popover and load VC2 in the process.  If you want to add that as an answer I can then accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be ok if you pass a VC1 reference to your PopOver. Then if you want to move to VC2 you need to do this on the VC1 reference and call dismiss onto the PopOver.